# How to pivot below data in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot, pivot-table

I have like below data in a oracle table.

```
ID      SEQ        PROD_ID       EXPIRE_DATE       
849123  134228     MZ321        12/03/2011 12:19:11   
849123  434128     MZ328        18/04/2012 12:09:11  
849123  424128     MZ326        16/02/2017 11:19:11  
849123  431128     MZ323        15/06/2012 12:29:11  
443121  133228     MZ321        12/03/2011 12:39:16  
443121  234128     MZ328        13/04/2012 12:40:19  
443121  424828     MZ326        19/02/2017 11:42:12  
443121  731129     MZ323        14/06/2012 12:45:19
```

I want to write sql statement to get the data in below format.
First column should have ID.

Second column should have EXPIRE_DATE of PROD_ID MZ321.

Third column should have EXPIRE_DATE of PROD_ID MZ326.

Fourth column should have SEQ of PROD_ID MZ321.

Fifth column should have SEQ of PROD_ID MZ326.
Sample O/P

```
ID       MZ321_EXPDATE        MZ326_EXPDATE         MZ321_SEQ  MZ326_SEQ  
849123   12/03/2011 12:19:11  16/02/2017 11:19:11   134228     424128  
443121   12/03/2011 12:39:16  19/02/2017 11:42:12   133228     424828
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please post your attempts; this will help people to understand the issues with your code and help you in improving it

Answer (score 1):

I would just use conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when PROD_ID = 'MZ321' then expire_date end) as MZ321_EXPDATE,
       max(case when PROD_ID = 'MZ326' then expire_date end) as MZ326_EXPDATE,
       max(case when PROD_ID = 'MZ321' then seq end) as MZ321_seq,
       max(case when PROD_ID = 'MZ326' then seq end) as MZ326_seq
from t
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the results should be grouped by ID.

It seems there's no need to restrict the ***second*** and ***third*** columns with certain values such as `MZ321` and `MZ326` for `PROD_ID`s. Since if you determine the ***minimum*** and ***maximum*** values for `expire_date` column, you might directly get the respective values for `EXPDATE` and `SEQ` columns directly as follows :

```
select q.*, 
       ( select seq from tab where expire_date = q.expdate1 and id = q.id ) as seq1,
       ( select seq from tab where expire_date = q.expdate2 and id = q.id ) as seq2       
  from     
 (
  select id, min(expire_date) as expdate1,
             max(expire_date) as expdate2
    from tab
   group by id
  ) q;

ID      EXPDATE1                EXPDATE2                SEQ1    SEQ2
------  ---------------------   ---------------------   ------  ------
849123  2011-03-12 12:19:11.0   2017-02-16 11:19:11.0   134228  424128
443121  2011-03-12 12:39:16.0   2017-02-19 11:42:12.0   133228  424828
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b70c8b/8)